# openGL picking after glTranslate / glRotated

Tags: opengl, pyopengl, mouse-picking

I wrote a pick function, to pick scene objects from the opengl canvas.

```
glRenderMode(GL_SELECT)
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
glPushMatrix()
glLoadIdentity()
gluPickMatrix(self.last_point_2D_.x(),viewport[3]-self.last_point_2D_.y(),10,10,viewport)
glMultMatrixf(projection)

glInitNames()
glPushName(0)

//i scene objects rendering goes here, drawn in modelview
glLoadName(i)

glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
glPopMatrix()
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
glFlush()
glPopName()
```

This works perfect if i do not use glTanslate or glRotated in drawing the object 
i.e, i can pick line when i draw,

```
glVertex3f(1,1,1)
glVertex3f(2,2,2)
```

but not when i do,

```
glTranslate(1,1,1)
glVertex3f(0,0,0)
glVertex3f(1,1,1)
```

What am i missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're still in projection matrix mode, when applying the translation, thus messing up the picking matrix. Switch to modelview before transforming the scene.